Wordpress CPT UI category doesnt show on my page
I would like to explain what i need as i can:
I am using Astra template.
I have a CPT called Projects with slug projects and I have 1 page called Projects with slug projects and have 3 childs called House, Flat and Tower, these 4 pages are using a template with Archive Title (works fine) and Archive Post that only works on projects page, but show me all projects i have.
What i need is if i go to my page XXXX/projects i want only to show me Category projects, if i go to my page XXXX/projects/house i want to show me all archive with category projects and house (or only house)
I am not using a custom category, just the normal Categories.
Also, I want to specific that on XXXX/projects/house, /flat, /tower are showing me the Post that I added to test but from my Custom Post doesnt show me
I have tried everything, changing archive.php and adding archive-projects.php and the samething.
